# Java JPanel clear

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I need to create a 2d simulation, but while setting a new "frame" the old dont get cleared.

I want some Circles moving in an Arena, and every loop the old circles should get removed and new ones spawn. Everything works, but the old ones dont get cleared and are still visible, thats what I need to change.

GameLoop

```
@Override
public void run() {

    while(true){

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
            for(Schleimpilz s : this.pilz){
                s.move();
                fenster.getArena().repaint();;
                fenster.getArena().paintPilz();

            }


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Thats the Arena Class (extends Jpanel), where the Jpanel needs to get cleared

```
public void paintPilz() {

    //how to clear the old values here?
    super.paintComponent(graphics);  
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    for(Schleimpilz s : schleimpilz){

        printNewSchleimpilz(s.getLocX(), s.getLocY());

    }
}
```

Comment: Call `super.paintComponent(graphics);` from outside the context of the `paintComponent` is just asking for trouble, where did `graphics` come from? See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting should be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing all of your rendering in the paintComponent method. This is how to old shapes get removed (on repaint).

To do your animation / creating new circles, you should use a javax.swing.Timer instead of Thread.sleep

```
new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                 s.move();
                fenster.getArena().repaint();
});
```